# Dynamo connected to a motor question

Tags: motor

[image]

Brief explanation: From the figure above, (B) is an electrical motor and (A) is a Dynamo, the red mark is a rotating rod connected to the dynamo. The dynamo is supplying power to the motor (B), hence the motor is getting more power which in turn makes the rod rotates faster.

Is the rod RPM going to keep increasing non stop or is it going to stop at a certain RPM and not increase any further?

Comment: Neither. The rod will slow down and eventually stop. How long that takes depends on the rotating mass (angular momentum) and the sum of all electrical and mechanical losses. Unless you are also supplying current to the motor at the point marked V.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about debunking a perpetual motion machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Let's say you can get 20 W out of your dynamo.
- Its efficiency is < 100% (it always is). Let's say it's 80% so you will need to put in 25% more mechanical energy in than you hope to obtain in electrical energy. That means you will need 25 W of mechanical power from the motor.
- You are now just wasting 20% of the motor output as heat in the dynamo. This is before we look at the extra heat generated in the motor.

You are inventing "free energy" or "perpetual motion". Since these violate the laws of thermodynamics they can't work.

Answer (score 2):

> So here's my question, is the rod RPM going to keep increasing non stop or is it going to stop at a certain RPM and not increase any further?

Sorry this is not going to work the way you think it does.

The generator is removing power from the motor and a proportion of that power is converted to electrical energy which you could feed back to the supply, (not as you have shown..) but because of conversion losses, i.e. efficiency, you will always feed back less power than you remove from the motor.

As such, hooking up that arrangement will slow the motor, not accelerate it. It will settle at a slower speed than it would run with the dynamo wire disconnected.